# compare two column the type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns called `T1_Address` and `B2_Address`, type `varchar`. How can I compare whether these two columns are the same?

```
T1_Address = Avenida Siempre viva 123
B2_Address = Avenida Siempre viva 123
```

Example

```
SELECT COUNT(0) 
FROM TABLA_MAESTRA 
WHERE G_NUMERO_OPERACION = '3333' 
    AND G_DOCTYPE = 'SEGURO_I_S' 
    AND T1_Address = B2_Address
```

the result of this is 0.

Comment: Check for extra spaces and the like. If those two columns really were the same in the row, and the other conditions are met, you'd see the row in the results.

Comment: I found my mistake. It is a different row where you should compare the record, it is not the same row.

then I must make two select one to bring me the column of the first record, and another to bring me the column of the second record.

Comment: If that's the problem, you don't need two SELECT statements. You need one SELECT statement where you JOIN the table back to itself.

Answer (score 0):

That should work as you have it, maybe check the collation of both columns.  And also check for embedded tabs and carriage returns.

Comment: it could also be one of the other parts of the where clause. G_NUMERO_OPERACION = '3333' AND G_DOCTYPE = 'SEGURO_I_S'

Comment: I found my mistake. It is a different row where you should compare the record, it is not the same row.

then I must make two select one to bring me the column of the first record, and another to bring me the column of the second record.